# How to Deploy a Workflow in the WindowsAzure Cloud?

Tags: .net, workflow, azure, biztalk

Is it possible to deploy a WF (4.0) creating using .Net 4.0 in the windowsAzure cloud? Do we need to purchase a seperate BizTalk server account for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to dynamically generate workflows and execute it in Azure. There are some limitations today as the instance store script will need some modifications as SQL Azure doesn't support some keywords.
I am in the windows workflow foundation team and we are working on making the experience of building, deploying workflows easier on Azure and I would be happy to chat with you on any issues that you are having using WF4 on Azure and understand your scenario better. If you like, please contact me ramesesh@hotmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Azure will currently run (almost) anything a Windows 2008 R2 x64 server running IIS 7.5 can. The .NET 4.0 Framework runtimes are installed.

So long as you could deploy your WF service to a stock (but up-to-date) 2008 R2 server, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Taylor for the answer. I have one more concern, is it possible to create workflows dynamically? I need to generate a WF dynamically based on a set of business logic and service execution sequence I get as input to the system. Is it possible for me to generate the workflow.xaml dynamically without using the wf designer and execute in the cloud ?

Comment: Sadly that extends beyond my knowledge of workflow.  If that concept is possible on a "traditional" server setup than it is possible in Azure.  If you figure it out locally and have trouble translating to Azure, please post that question then and we can prob steer ya in the right direction